# Optimizing callstack for a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, memory, depth-first-search

I have a node which can generate adjacent members, via `node.create_adj_list()`, and I need to process a tree or graph with a recursive function, but I had some questions about the memory efficiency. Each node has a list of solutions that I need to gather.

Say I have this code, a DFS search:

```
total_solutions = []

def handle_node(node):
  for solution in find_solutions(node):
    total_solutions.append(solution)
  for adj_node in node.create_adj_list():
    handle_node(adj_node)
```

If I call `handle_node` on a parent node, to my understanding what happens is:

1. our parent node exists in memory
2. we generate solutions for that node
3. we generate the existence of adjacent nodes, storing them in memory
4. we recurse down the tree in a DFS fashion

If our tree looks like this:

```
     O
    / \
   O   O
  / \
 O   O
```

As we recurse through the tree, we start on the left-most part of the tree and DFS down. But as we travel down this branch, we are also generating the children of each node from that branch, and storing those in memory. Doesn't this mean we are storing O(m*n) in memory, where `m` is the depth of the tree and `n` is the average number of children?

This seems really inefficient, as we shouldn't need to store all those children nodes in memory, we should just be able to store the depth in memory only.

How should I resolve this situation to make my code not store things in memory unnecessarily?

My initial thoughts are that `create_adj_list()` method is maybe not good.

Comment: You are prematurely optimizing.  Write the code that is simplest to write and for your readers to understand.  If this really turns out to be the bottleneck of your program and it is critical that it run as quickly as possible, then fix it.  But any time you spend on this code is probably more time than the code itself will ever save.

Comment: I'm not sure where those assumptions are coming from, this is a conceptual question for understanding, not for an end product.

Comment: These adjacency lists only exist temporarily. When you return from that recursion level, the list will become garbage and the memory will be reclaimed.

Comment: @Barmar Unclear why you're saying that. They're not concerned about memory being used permanently. They're concerned about that temporary memory usage.

Comment: *"create_adj_list() method is maybe not good"* - Yeah, maybe. But we can't tell because we can't even see it.

Comment: Maybe you can implement `create_adj_list()` as a generator, so you don't have to instantiate the list and fill up memory.

Comment: if `find_solutions` and `create_adj_list` are generated values, you can process them ad hoc, without storing intermediate results a list